The same content script has been injected twice into a browser tab
console log showing vm72 inject.jsI am creating a timer to track how long im watching a youtube video for, and my background.js automatically injects all tabs with the content script, this has been working fine and the timer has been accurate. However now i'm seeing messages from "VM72 inject.js", which contains the same code as my content script but its also running alongside, which I don't want.
When I close all windows and tabs and start again it works, and I only get logs from inject.js. Which is cool but I want to know what caused this and how to resolve and ensure it doesn't get duplicated again.
